# Symfony Cache Definition Problem with PDO Adapter

Tags: php, symfony, pdo

I am upgrading a Symfony 5.4 project to 6.2. While doing this, I encountered the following error:

> Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\PdoAdapter::__construct(): Argument #1
> ($connOrDsn) must be of type PDO|string, Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
> given

This is my Cache Config:

```
framework:
    cache:
        default_pdo_provider: 'doctrine.dbal.default_connection'
        pools:
            login_throttling.cache:
                adapter: cache.adapter.pdo
```

This worked in 5.4 and the docs for 6.2 are also suggesting that this config is correct: https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html

But the upgrade guide in the symfony github page has this information:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.3/UPGRADE-6.0.md#cache

> PdoAdapter does not accept Doctrine\DBAL\Connection or DBAL URL. Use
> the new DoctrineDbalAdapter instead

But it is unclear what the name for the new adapter is.

The whole approach is based on this: https://blog.digital-craftsman.de/login-throttling-with-symfony-and-multiple-server-instances/

Answer (score 3):

Solved. The correct config uses `cache.adapter.doctrine_dbal` instead of `cache.adapter.pdo` in the pool config.